# How to fix "color depth (32 bits per pixel) is not supported" error in Captiva recognition?

Tags: opentext, captiva, captiva-designer

I am trying to configure a classification in Captiva Recognition. Whenever I am trying to take a tiff file(created from ms paint) for classification, its says "color depth (32 bits per pixel) is not supported". On checking, I noticed that all the MS paint files by default convert to 32 pixel.

[image]

How can I configure Captiva to work with 32 bit TIFF files also?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently I created all the tiff images from pdf(As I needed tiff files to create template for classification). In all other ways there were different configurations which Captiva was not supporting.

I created a sample conversion project to convert pdf to tiff and used those tiffs to create rthe templates and it fixed the issue.